# How can I do a dump of only the table structure in PostgreSQL?

Tags: backup, database, postgresql, restore, schema

In a similar vein to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/54413/how-can-i-backup-a-table-structure-but-not-his-data-in-mysql/), how would I do a schema-only dump in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`pg_dump --schema-only`

Comment: easier than I realized it would be :)

Comment: Frankly, I haven't much clue about postgres administration, but I've been watching videos from pgcon 09 and someone mentioned pg_dump.

Comment: either way - it's what I needed :)

Comment: @warren: it's even easier: `pg_dump -s`.

Comment: This command dumps everything and not only *table* structure: --schema-only Dump only the object definitions (schema), not data [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

Answer (score 19):

If you only want the `CREATE TABLE` statements, then you can do `pg_dump -s databasename | awk 'RS="";/CREATE TABLE[^;]*;/'`

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes as this command works perfectly. So +1 from me.

Comment: That was the rigth answer to me, because i couldn't create file with functions, views and etc.

Comment: @Dave because adding an additional option not at all linked to the initial question 6 years later is not that useful.

Comment: @Arne. Disagree. The question title, which specifies dumping "only the table structure", gives this page a high search rank. And plenty of people, like Natan who remarked prior to you, want to avoid moving functions and/or views from old extensions in the event that they are starting with a fresh db with updated extensions. So it absolutely is "useful", as opposed to "not useful", which are the voting criteria. Absolutely getting my +1.

Comment: @Dave. I think that this answer is right. I opened because the title. I'm searching table-only struct dump. This is better than the other or the title is not acurated.

Comment: This awk command didn't work for me - it returned everything. Perhaps there has been some syntax change since the original post?

Comment: @nonethewiser syntax has not changed AFAIK

Comment: @arod I am not familiar with awk but see there are a few different implementations (mawk, gawk). I am on macOS. I ended up going a different direction but believe either it has to do with that, or I am having a totally different issue. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @nonethewiser I'm not too familiar with awk either (or the other ones), but it seems like your SQL statements don't end with  ";" each one? That could make this approach fail...